# ${mail_host } macro on sendmail.mc is returning an empty value

Tags: linux, sendmail

I've created a custom header and I'm trying to set its value to something like `username::domain:servername`. For example, messages from `user@mydomain.com` using myserver as the MTA should generate a header value of `user::mydomain.com.:myserver`.

I've put this in my sendmail.cf:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
HFeedback-ID: ${mail_addr}::${mail_host}:$w
```

However when I see the emails that were sent this header looks like this:

```
Feedback-ID: user:::myserver
```

For some reason the `${mail_host}` macro seems to be returning an empty value. Should I be using a different macro? How can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `HFeedback-ID: $&{mail_host}`

Comment: I tried that and it actually arrived as a japanese character:
`Feedback-ID: user:ぉ:myserver`